# What are the plurals of "maschio" and "femmina" as adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, agreement, plural

I have read that in Italian, the words *maschio* and *femmina* can be used as adjectives after the names of animals to specify that an animal is male or female, and that these adjectives are invariable in this context, so a singular feminine noun still takes *maschio* (like *la giraffa maschio*) and a single masculine noun still takes *femmina*: [Modern Italian Grammar: A Practical Guide](https://www.ladante-nice.fr/images/grammar.pdf),

But *maschio* and *femmina* don't seem to always be invariable between singular and plural when used as adjectives: for example, there is a phrase *[colleghi maschi](https://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/colleghi+maschi)* which Reverso says means "male colleagues".

So I'm confused about what the plural forms are like with animals: should I say *le giraffe maschio*, *le giraffe maschi,* or are both used? One source I found gave examples of *maschio* and *femmina* with plural animals ([Using Italian
A Guide to Contemporary Usage](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Using_Italian/AvrittnqXIEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22maschio%22+%22maschi%22+invariable&pg=PA240&printsec=frontcover), By J. J. Kinder, V. M. Savini, 2004, page 240). But also, when I searched online for "le giraffe maschi", I found many examples; e.g.

> Quanto sono alte le giraffe?
>
> **Le giraffe maschi** possono superare i 5,5 metri (18 piedi) di altezza e **le giraffe femmine** possono raggiungere circa 4,5 metri (circa 14 piedi).

(https://delphipages.live/it/scienza/mammiferi/mammiferi-ungulati/giraffe)

Comment: Invariable in gender perhaps, but certainly not in number.

Comment: Are you sure, @DenisNardin? [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/maschio), among other examples, gives _lepri maschio_ (and, for what's worth, it agrees with what I'd have said).

Comment: I would use *le giraffe maschio* but I would use *i maschi di giraffa*.

Comment: ***Nomi  di genere promiscuo.*** Per precisare il sesso di  animali che hanno un’unica forma, maschile o femminile, si può usare: ***l’apposizione maschio / femmina***; 

*un leopardo maschio

la zebra maschio*

***o – meglio – l’espressione il maschio / la femmina di, del***; 

*il maschio della tigre

la femmina di gnu

la femmina del leopardo* https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/genere-promiscuo_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/

Comment: I’d avoid the expression “giraffe maschi” and use the more common “I maschi delle giraffe”.

Comment: I agree, @Hachi, but if I were forced to use the former construction I'd say _le giraffe maschio_, per Treccani (“sempre al masch. anche se riferito a nomi femm., e al sing. anche se riferito a nomi plur.”). _Giraffe maschi_, the cited website notwithstanding, sound alien to me.

Comment: Given that all that follows is just a personal idea which I would not be able to substantiate with any resource, I think in the language spoken every day the adjective "_maschio_" stays invariable in number when the noun is invariable in gender but can be consistent in number with the noun, when the noun is variable in gender (while the adjective "_femmina_" remains always invariable). [...continue...]

Comment: [...] For example, "_giraffa_" is invariable whether it indicates a male, a female or an individual of unkown sex, so we say "_giraffa/e maschi**o**_" and "_giraffa/e femmin**a**_" (no number consistency) if we want to refer to a specific sex. [...continue...]

Comment: [...] On the other hand, for nouns that vary between sexes, it is not uncommon to make the adjective "_maschio_" consistent with the number of the noun: for a group of all-male dogs, you can hear both "_i cani maschi**o**_" and "_i cani masch**i**_" (the latter being probably wrong from the grammatical point of view but widely used nonetheless, at least in my experience) while for a group of all-female dogs you can hear "_le cagne_" (the sex is indicated by the noun itself) or "_i cani femmin**a**_" (no number consistency) but I think you'll never hear "_i cani femmin**e**_".

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell why but it should be "le giraffe maschio" or il maschio delle giraffe". Same would be "il coccodrillo" > "i coccodrilli femmina". This is what sounds correct, at least.

Comment: If you "can't tell why", apart from the fact the something "sounds correct", then you are not really answering a question, according to the standards of the community. That kind of comments belongs to... well, comments. ;)